# How do I show that $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2} \le \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|?$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality, summation

How do I show that $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2} \le \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|?$

I was studying Spivak's book and I found this questions. I have no idea how to solve, I really appreciate any comments/suggestions, etc.

Comment: Already answered here, if you know the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664992/vector-lengths-how-to-prove-this-inequality/1664996#1664996

Comment: @Cheese, thanks!

Comment: See also: [Prove that $ \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^2} \le \sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_j|$, for all $a_i \in \mathbb{R}, i=\{1,2,...,n\}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/163053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take the triangle inequality as known: In $\mathbb R^n$ consider $\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_ke_k.$ Then the triangle inequality gives

$$ (x_1^2 +\cdots +x_n^2)^{1/2} = |\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_ke_k| \le \sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_ke_k| = \sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_k|.$$

Comment: this is a nice approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Both sides are non-negative sums of non-negative terms: square both sides

$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|\right)^2$$

The above is true since in the right sum appear all the summands that are in the left side and other non-negative ones (you can prove this directly, by induction say). For example, with three we have

$$ (|x_1|+x_2|+|x_3|)^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^22|x_1x_2|+\ldots\ge x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$$

Now just take square roots.

Comment: If it helps, the right side can also be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \ne i} |x_i x_j|$.

Comment: @nukeguy Thank you, I just wanted to do things simple for the asker. In fact a somewhat simpler expression is possible for that right side: $$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2+2\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}|x_ix_j|$$

Comment: thank you, I appreciate your answer.